# Replace launching activity with flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is it possible to replace the activity that gets the intent-filter

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

by configuring flavors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just add a manifest file in the folder of the product flavour and

> The Manifest of the product flavor is merged on top of the Manifest of the main configuration.

More info here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-system-concepts

Comment: does this merge remove the intent-filter from one manifest and adds it on the other?

Comment: It should do that, if not, just add a main intent filter for each product flavour  and remove in the default manifest.

Answer (score 10):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this thanks to the [manifest merger](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger).

The easiest way is to use a placeholder in your manifest and define the appropriate class in your build.gradle.

For example, in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name="${launchActivityName}">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And in your build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ launchActivityName:"com.example.MainActivity"]
    }
}
```

You can also include a different manifest file with each flavor.

Comment: This will not work if wanted to have different feature, like one is regular launcher and another flavor with Home-Launcher application. Any suggestion to do that !!

Comment: @shubh I'm not quite following- you should post a new question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Tanis answer, I want to add some parts you should aware of.

```
productFlavors {
    lite {
        dimension "default"
        applicationId "com.foo.bar"
        manifestPlaceholders = [ applicationLabel:"@string/app_name_foo"
                                 , launcherAct: "com.foo.qux.activity.Hello"
                                 , launcherAct2: "com.foo.qux.activity.World"]
    }
    full {
        dimension "default"
        applicationId "com.foo.qux"
        manifestPlaceholders = [ applicationLabel:"@string/app_name_bar"
                                 , launcherAct: ".activity.World"
                                 , launcherAct2: ".activity.Hello"]
    }
}
```

1. If let's say, your `World.java` exists in `com.foo.qux.activity` folder, then you should use **full path** `com.foo.qux.activity.World` instead of `.activity.World` when put it inside `applicationId "com.foo.bar"` flavor, or else it will auto prepend to `com.foo.bar.activity.World` which the file doesn't exist.
2. Unlike `android:label`, you can't use something like **`@string/launcher_class`** in `android:name`, or else you will get `error: attribute 'android:name' in <activity> tag must be a valid Java class name.` when build.
3. Ensures you don't duplicate the class, e.g. :

   ```
   <activity
       android:name="${launcherAct}"
       android:label="${applicationLabel}">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   <activity
       android:name="${launcherAct2}"
       android:label="${applicationLabel}">
   </activity>
   ```

Don't forgot to change from `.activity.World` to `android:name="${launcherAct2}"` or else you end up **duplicated activity** (i.e. one in `AndroidManifest.xml`, the other one in `manifestPlaceholders`).

4. The `Unresolved class` **red indicator can safely ignored**, seems like Android Studio bug:
   [image]

I make a bug report [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119883862).